# How to remove an image from gridview by using cross sign at the corner(Android)?

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcOSZ.jpg)

i have already created gridview.i want to remove the images by a single click.
thank u.

Comment: You can onClick of cross of the itemview remove from list and then call notifyDatasetchange. or post your code what you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple,

Assuming that you are using `recyclerview`

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View vCross;

    ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        vCross = itemView.findViewById(R.id.your_view_id) // Giving reference
        vCross .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // Assuming dataset is your adapter dataset
                    dataSet.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                    notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });
    }
}
```

*Summary,* 
 In your `ViewHolder`, when user clicks on remove button - remove item from your adapter dataSet and notify `adapter` that, item has been removed at specific position.